# CSS styles not reflecting in reactapp

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a button component in react js. I'm able to render the bootstrap classes. But, I need to override some css rules in bootstrap. for that I have created a styles variable. But, it's throwing error.

parent.js

```
 <Button   buttonType={TYPES.DANGER} label="Add To Cart" onClick={() => this.addItemToCart(pdpList.uniqueID)}></Button>
```

button.js

```
 import React from 'react';

 const styles ={
 background-color:  #EF3829 !important;
 color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
 }

export const TYPES = {
 PRIMARY: 'btn-primary',
 WARNING: 'btn-warning',
 DANGER: 'btn-danger',
 SUCCESS: 'btn-success',
 }

  export const Button = (props) => (
   <button  
    onClick={props.onClick} 
      className={props.styles,[ props.buttonType || TYPES.PRIMARY] }
    >
   {props.label}
   </button>
 );
```

Can some please help me to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Where is the error

Comment: it's showing error what I have declared inside styles variable

Comment: Not sure if typo, but it looks like you're not using strings to define your styling in that styles variable.  Also, injecting styles in React components is a bit different in syntax.

Comment: What was this line suppose to do? `className={props.styles,[ props.buttonType || TYPES.PRIMARY] }` This expression is equivalent to `[ props.buttonType || TYPES.PRIMARY]` (this is how comma operator works) making className an array of 1 element while it should be a string.

Comment: @yourfavoritedev Will you help me to troubleshoot

Comment: I wrote props.styles to override the bootstrap styles. But, I want the styles also in that className. How to proceed with that one. @YuryTarabanko

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya sure friend! See my answer below and let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following-up, to inject styles in React components, you must treat your styles like a standard Javascript object. Each style needs a key and a value. For styles, the value is always a string.

```
 import React from 'react';

 const styles = {
    backgroundColor: "#EF3829",
    color: "#fff",
    borderRadius: "0px"
 }

export const TYPES = {
 PRIMARY: 'btn-primary',
 WARNING: 'btn-warning',
 DANGER: 'btn-danger',
 SUCCESS: 'btn-success',
 }

  export const Button = (props) => (
   <button  
      onClick={props.onClick} 
      style={styles}
      className={ props.buttonType || TYPES.PRIMARY }
    >
   {props.label}
   </button>
 );
```

Comment: Yes the styles error has gone. But, its not taking the styles. You can see right, I have declared the bootstrap variables like btn-primary etc. But, I want to override some properties to custom. So, how do  I override it

Comment: I just made an update. Realizing that you can't use important tags for inline-styles. Also the property is style, not styles. can you try that out.

Answer (score 1):

First

the styles object should be like this:

```
const styles ={
    background-color:  '#EF3829 !important'; // the value should be an object.. or a variable
    color: '#fff';
    border-radius: '0px !important';
}
```

Second

I think the className of a button should be a string.

If you want to add your own inline style, you can the style attribute like this.